# delete if key = value Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a ruby script that I need to convert to Groovy, its a simple case of removing a collection if `key: value`.

So in my setup I make a request to the github api

```
def jsonParse(def json) {
  new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
}

def request = sh script: """curl https://api.github.com/repos/org/${repo}/releases?access_token=${env.TOKEN}""", returnStdout: true
def list = jsonParse(request)
return list
```

This returns output like so

```
[
  [prerelease: 'true', author: [surname: 'surname', book: 'title'], surname: 'surname'],
  [prerelease: 'false', author: [surname: 'surname', book: 'title'], surname: 'surname']
]
```

In Ruby i would do the following

```
array.delete_if { |key| key['prerelease'] == true }
```

How would I approach this with Groovy, if an explanation could be provided that would also be great so i can learn from it

Update

Using the approach from @Rao my list is exactly the same

```
def request = sh script: """curl https://api.github.com/repos/org/${repo}/releases?access_token=${env.TOKEN}""", returnStdout: true
def list = jsonParse(request)
list.removeAll(list.findAll{it.prerelease == 'true'})
return list
```

Raw response

```
[
  {"prerelease": true, "author": [ {"surname": "surname", "book": "title"}, "surname": "surname"],
  {"prerelease": false, "author": [ {"surname": "surname", "book": "title"}, "surname": "surname"]
]
```

Comment: Be very careful with nomenclature. In Java and Groovy an array and a `List` are different. Arrays are fixed-length. Lists can shrink and grow. What you have here is a `List` of `Map`s.

Comment: thanks for the clarification :-)

Comment: @Richlewis, see my answer if you are still looking for it.

Comment: @Richlewis, can you please show the raw response of `sh script` result?

Comment: so just `return request` ?

Comment: No, raw text /response of curl. Because, you are updated with parsing `Json`.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146153/room-for-rao-and-richlewis

Answer (score 1):

e. g. with

```
array = array.findAll { it.prerelease != 'true' }
```

I guess you don't need anymore explanation?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I confused `true` and `false`. You have to find all that are not `true` of course. I updated my answer. Besides that, you always talk about "array", but those are maps. There is no such thing as an associative array in Groovy besides maps.

Comment: ah sorry, think i got my wires crossed, i keep thinking of the data structure I have as an array of hashes

Comment: Actually what you posted is a list of maps :-)

Comment: ah sorry, think i got my wires crossed, i keep thinking of the data structure I have as an array of hashes, so i would like to remove a map from the list if prerelease == true

Comment: Yes, sure, my answer is still correct to this requirement

Answer (score 1):

The sample data is list of maps.

Need to remove the items from the list by filtering `prerelease` is equal to `true`. Hope this is string only as embedded between the quotes.

Here is the script which results filtered list.

```
def list = [   
  [prerelease: 'true', author: [surname: 'surname', book: 'title'], surname: 'surname'],
  [prerelease: 'true', author: [surname: 'surname', book: 'title'], surname: 'surname'],
  [prerelease: 'false', author: [surname: 'surname', book: 'title'], surname: 'surname'] 
]

//Remove all those elements(map) from list if matching the condition
list.removeAll(list.findAll{it.prerelease == 'true'})

//Show the updated list
println list
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5137258231365632)</kbd>

EDIT: based on OP comment.

Isn't this below output what you want?
[image]

**EDIT2: Based on OP changed response as Json**

```
def json = """[
  {"prerelease": true, "author": [ {"surname": "surname", "book": "title"}]},
  {"prerelease": false, "author": [ {"surname": "surname", "book": "title"}]}
]"""
list = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(list.findAll{ it.prerelease != true }).toPrettyString()
```

[image]

Comment: This is correct, but (a) it's less efficient than @Richlewis 's solution and (b) avoiding mutating an existing data structure is good.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have to admit, rather confused here, `println list` is returning the same set of results but in this format `[{prerelease=true}]` for example and the list is not getting removed.. and it i `return list` i just get the output `false`

Comment: @Richlewis, would you please check the edit with output?

Comment: thats exactly what I want but when i run it in my application i get different results, something must be happening that im not aware of or understanding, I'm going to update my question with more info with regards to my setup

Comment: @Richlewis, you may want to use `return list` at the end of the script? See if that helps.

Comment: @Richlewis, have you check with the [script](https://github.com/nmrao/groovyScripts/blob/master/test.groovy) and worked as desired?